# How do I use a combination of attributes to select a button in Selenium?

Tags: selenium, java, xpath, css-selectors

I'm trying to get selenium to select a simple button that says next. I've tried XPath, CSS, and linktext and it still will not select it for me saying it cannot locate the element. Here is the code.

Edit: The button is inside an i-frame.

```
<button class="btn-next" href="#" data-next="true">Next</button>
```

Not sure why it cannot locate the element, this is the xpath that came out from it but still It cannot locate it.

```
findElement(By.Xpath(".//*[@id='step1']/button"))
```

It seems I was missing some of the HTML. Here is the entire part.

```
div class="form-container">
<form data-capture="true" data-ajax="false" method="post">
<div id="view1" class="view active_view" data-view-order="10"     style="display: none;">
<div id="step1">
<ul class="btns">
<div class="clear"/>
<h1>I'm a</h1>
<h2>
<button class="btn-next" href="#" data-next="true">Next</button>
```

Comment: Did you grab that xpath before or after the action that led you to that button, i.e. any dynamic page stuff, ajax, animations, single page form, etc. ?

Comment: Nope went straight from opening browser to this page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually found out why the above was not working.

The issue is that it was inside an`iframe`.

```
<iframe id="index_reg_iframe" src="/main.php? a=user.register_iframe_fp&amp;no_header=1&amp;btn_bg_next=447DC3&amp;btn_ bg_next_hover=396ba8&amp;id=noadvert&amp;prg=1&amp;tour=1&amp;pg=1" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" hspace="0" vspace="0" scrolling="no" allowtransparency="true" height="450" frameborder="0" width="410"></iframe>
```

The following command worked for me.

```
driver.switchTo().frame("index_reg_iframe").findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='step1']/button")).click();
```

Thank you guys for brainstorming with me.

Answer (score 3):

The HTML you show has no ID (it's **not** the href that has a `#` btw, that's different).

so

```
findElement(By.Xpath(".//*[@id='step1']/button"))`
```

will not work based on what you posted.

You could use:

Css is always my first go to for readability:
`findElement(By.Css(".btn-next[data-next='true']"))`

or by Class:
`findElement(By.Class("btn-next"))`

or by XPath
`findElement(By.XPath("//*[@data-next]"))`

or your issue may be that multiple exist and you need multiple qualifiers:

by Xpath example:
`findElement(By.XPath("//*[@data-next][@class='btn-next']"))`

etc.

Based on your new update with the HTML you could use:

```
By.Css("form div#step1 button.btn-next")
```

if it exists twice you might need:

```
By.Css("form div#step1 ul.buttons button.btn-next")
```

or

```
By.Css("form div#step1 ul.buttons button.btn-next:first-of-type")
```

You might need to put the first-of-type on the form, the div, the ul, etc.

as you can see the pattern with css is to have the elements and any qualifiers in a short compact format.
it depends on the rest of the page and if it has the stuff repeated

Comment: Unfortunately none of the above worked. I do believe it exists more than twice as the steps make it go to 6, ex fill one part out hit next. fill the box part out hit next. No matter what code I put to find the next button though it comes back as cannot find element.

Comment: try the `first_of_type` qualifier that I've added above on the last entry.

Comment: and you tried with the added `ul.buttons` right ?

Comment: I did, it still gives me an error of not able to find the element.

Comment: I just realized that the button is inside of an iframe, Not sure if that helps.

Comment: see updated note.  At this point please post **the entire** HTML source  somewhere like https://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: To debug this, please say what does work.  Does Find.ByCss('body') work?  Does find.ByCss("body form:first_of_type") work, etc.  until you get to find out the exact issue.

Comment: re: iframe, well yes you could add iframe at the start of the css identifiers `iframe form `...

Comment: is there any ajax or animation being fired?  You may need to use a wait strategy for the element to be present.  To _diagnose_ the issue try adding a 3 second sleep.  This is **not** a good fix but useful for diagnosis of the issue.  The real fix is a wait that is constantly checking for the element and eventually timing out.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason why you do not choose `findElement(By.Class("btn-next"))`
Without being able to see the whole DOM it is hard to say why exactly your Path does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this xpath -

```
"//button[@class='btn-next'][.='Next']"
```

Is the button visible when the selector is fired? If not first verify with ExpectedConditions if it is visible or clickable.